# Web font in email not displaying

Tags: css, email, fonts, nodemailer

I use [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) to handle my emails. I am trying to apply Poppins as a font for the text in my html body. Currently I have the following code:

```
    <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

          <style>
                 .text {
                      font-family: 'Poppins';
                  }
          </style>
   </head>


   <body>
        <p class="text">
             This is a paragraph
        </p>
   </body>
```

However the font is not applied to the paragraph. When I paste this html into a web browser (console tool) the paragraph has the font applied. My guess is that emails can't have embedded web fonts, but lots of articles say it's possible like [this](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts/), [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/web-fonts-in-email/) and [this](https://uplandsoftware.com/adestra/resources/blog/guide-web-fonts-emails/). I have tried using

```
@media screen {
   @font-face {
   }
}
```

and even other fonts like Montserrat as in the first article.

I have tested on outlook and gmail and neither works as wanted. The outlook version is Outlook 2016 (16.0.9126.2259).
Where/what am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Gmail does not support web fonts much.

Gmail officially only supports two web fonts: Open Sans and Roboto. Don't expect any other web font to render correctly in Gmail. However, there are many email clients which do support web fonts like Microsoft, Apple, etc. But, as Gmail is widely used by many, you would not want to use web fonts because of their non-universal support.

https://www.smartrmail.com/blog/email-safe-fonts-web-safe-fonts-for-email-explained

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This makes it understandable why it doesn't work for gmail. However, the question still stands for what is wrong for outlook.

Comment: it does not work in Outlook either: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2019/04/using-web-fonts-in-email.

Comment: Here's an up to date support chart for `@font-face` in email clients: https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/